# Improving poor performance of ArcPy update cursor with ArcSDE and Editor?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, cursor, performance, code-review

I am using ArcGIS 10.5 in an ArcSDE environment.

I have two tables, they are the exact same table schemas, but one is being edited and those edits are being pushed to the main table.  I am a little weak in my python (but learning) and I just started to work with da.cursors and I have gotten this script to work,  but both tables have 3800 records in them,  and when this runs to update it takes 4 hours.  This is just way too long imho.

I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong here but I dont know what it is.  Also I am open to any other suggestions on how to best accomplish this task.  Some people have suggested joining the two tables based on the UUID and then using the calculate tool to copy over all values,  some have suggested using a dictionary.

I also think I dont need the whole arcpy.da.Editor part, but that was in the code sample I found, so I was a little confused.

Please dont feel like I am asking anyone to do this for me,  I have gotten this to actually work, but it works very poorly and I am afraid my logic is not very elegant and may actually cause problems later on (like locked dbs, etc...)  I would just like a critique of the code and any suggestions on how to better accomplish this.

here is my code

```
Dump_FC = r'C:\Users\ME\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\CondemnationTimeline_UUID_xls_CondemnationTimeline_UUID'
Main_FC =  r'Database Connections\IS memvmtestsql3.XXX.ad.sde\IS_GDB.GISADMIN.PW_CodeEnforcement_CondemnationTimeline'


#Load all field names into list named field_names (crazy huh?)
dsc = arcpy.Describe(Dump_FC)
fields = dsc.fields

field_names = []

#Remove any field named ObjectID or ObjectID_1 and create list of fields

for field in fields:
    if field.name != "OBJECTID" and field.name != "OBJECTID_1" :
        print field.name + " != " + dsc.OIDFieldName + " " + str(field.name != dsc.OIDFieldName)
        field_names.append(field.name)
    else:
        continue

fc1 = r'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\CondemnationTimeline_UUID_xls_CondemnationTimeline_UUID'
fc1_fields = field_names
fc2 = r'Database Connections\IS memvmtestsql3.XXXX.ad.sde\IS_GDB.GISADMIN.PW_CodeEnforcement_CondemnationTimeline'
fc2_fields = field_names

# The Editor class allows use of edit sessions and operations to manage database transactions.
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)
edit.startEditing(True, False)
edit.startOperation()

i=1

print "starting main table update"

# Open an da.updateCursor on FC1 starting at ROW1 , at ROW1 open second da.updateCursor on FC2 and go ROW by ROW looking for matching GRID #

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc1, fc1_fields) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        cur2 = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc2, fc2_fields)
        print "on row ==================== " + str(i) + "   " + str(row[64])
        i = i + 1
        for row2 in cur2:
            print row2[64]
            if row[64] == row2[64]:   # if UUIDS in FC1 match FC2 then copy over all columns
                print "*** match found ***"

                j = 0
                while j < len(field_names):
                    row2[j] = row[j]
                    j = j + 1

            cur2.updateRow(row2)

del cur, cur2, row, row2

edit.stopOperation()
edit.stopEditing(True)
```

Answer (score 6):

The nested cursors are slowing you way down. Instead, use a searh cursor to create a dictionary with UIDs as your key and rows as your values. Then use an update cursor to update your second feature class.

```
fc1 = r'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\CondemnationTimeline_UUID_xls_CondemnationTimeline_UUID'
fc1_fields = field_names
fc2 = r'Database Connections\IS memvmtestsql3.XXXX.ad.sde\IS_GDB.GISADMIN.PW_CodeEnforcement_CondemnationTimeline'
fc2_fields = field_names

uidFld = "UID" #put your uid field name here
uidIndex = field_names.index (uidFld) #get index number of uid field.

#empty dictionary
di = {}

#search cursor fc1
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (fc1, fc1_fields) as curs:
    for row in curs:
        #get uid
        uid = row [uidIndex]
        #assign row to uid in dictionary
        di [uid] = row

#update cursor fc2
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (fc2, fc2_fields) as curs:
    for row in curs:
        #get uid
        uid = row [uidIndex]
        #get row
        row = di [uid]
        #update row
        curs.updateRow (row)
```

Note that if your tables have their rows **in the same order** you can skip the dictionary:

```
fc1 = r'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\CondemnationTimeline_UUID_xls_CondemnationTimeline_UUID'
fc1_fields = field_names
fc2 = r'Database Connections\IS memvmtestsql3.XXXX.ad.sde\IS_GDB.GISADMIN.PW_CodeEnforcement_CondemnationTimeline'
fc2_fields = field_names

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (fc1, fc1_fields) as curs1:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (fc2, fc2_fields) as curs2:
        for row in curs1:
            curs2.next ()
            curs2.updateRow (row)
```

Comment: Wow! Getting rid of the nested cursors and using a dictionary cut my processing time from 3 hours to 52 seconds. Thank you!